# Java DefaultMutableTree incompatible types

Tags: java, swing, types, jtree

Been searching for an answer online but haven't found anything yet.
I have created the following method

```
public void process(DefaultTreeModel tree){
    DefaultMutableTreeNode current = tree.getRoot();
}
```

However, the compiler is throwing an incompatible type error.
The tree is created by creating DefaultMutableTreeNodes from my own class, and then adding them to a DefaultMutableTree (tested and works fine).

Im not sure why the type is incompatible, because when i run the following

```
public void process(DefaultTreeModel tree){
    Object o = tree.getRoot();
    System.out.println(o.getClass());
}
```

It outputs:

```
class javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode
```

All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DefaultTreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#getRoot%28%29) returns an Object when you call getRoot().  The compiler has no information as to what type it will be at runtime, so it assumes it's an Object and cannot cast it to a DefaultMutableTreeNode.

Even if it's the right class at run time, it cannot know this at compile time.  You will have to check it with `instanceof`

```
Object o = tree.getRoot();
if(o instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)o;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, I thought it would be fine at run time. Definitely out of practice with Java. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#getRoot%28%29), you'll see that `getRoot` returns an `Object`. You can try casting:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode current = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getRoot();
```

`getClass` is probably returning `javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode` because this object is an *instance* of a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` (but its type is still `Object`, which is why you receive the error).

---

Relevant documentation:

- [`DefaultTreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html)
- [`DefaultMutableTreeNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `getRoot` returns an Object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#getRoot()

Try casting:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode current = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getRoot();
```